# How to remove a filename from the list of path in Shell

Tags: bash, shell

I would like to remove a file name only from the following configuration file.

*Configuration File* -- **test.conf**

```
knowledgebase/arun/test.rf
knowledgebase/arunraj/tester/test.drl
knowledgebase/arunraj2/arun/test/tester.drl
```

The above file should be read. And removed contents should went to another file called **output.txt**

Following are my try. It is not working to me at all. I am getting empty files only.

```
#!/bin/bash
file=test.conf
while IFS= read -r line
do
#       grep --exclude=*.drl line
#       awk 'BEGIN {getline line ; gsub("*.drl","", line) ; print line}'
#       awk '{ gsub("/",".drl",$NF); print line }' arun.conf
#       awk 'NF{NF--};1' line arun.conf
echo $line | rev | cut -d'/' -f 1 | rev >> output.txt
done < "$file"
```

**Expected Output :**

```
knowledgebase/arun
knowledgebase/arunraj/tester
knowledgebase/arunraj2/arun/test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [`dirname`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) command to make it easy and reliable:

```
#!/bin/bash
file=test.conf
while IFS= read -r line
do
    dirname "$line"
done < "$file" > output.txt
```

There are Bash [shell parameter expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) that will work OK with the list of names given but won't work reliably for some names:

```
file=test.conf
while IFS= read -r line
do
    echo "${line%/*}"
done < "$file" > output.txt
```

There's `sed` to do the job — easily with the given set of names:

```
sed 's%/[^/]*$%%' test.conf > output.txt
```

It's harder if you have to deal with names like `/plain.file` (or `plain.file` — the same sorts of edge cases that trip up the shell expansion).

You could add Perl, Python, Awk variants to the list of ways of doing the job.

Comment: Ed Morton's standard diatribe would apply here. "If you are using a shell loop to process a text file, you are doing it wrong."

Comment: That's why I included the `sed` option — that, or Perl or Python, is what I'd use for the given task.  It depends on whether there's anything else to do in the loop.  In my experience, you often need a `sort -u` to remove duplicate directories from the list of directories.  That's easily handled in any of the scripts though.  A 4-command pipeline per filename is horrendous compared to any of these solutions.

Answer (score 3):

Using awk one liner you can do this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {NF--} 1' test.conf
```

**Output:**

```
knowledgebase/arun
knowledgebase/arunraj/tester
knowledgebase/arunraj2/arun/test
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the path like this:

```
  path=${fullpath%/*}
```

It cuts away the string after the last /